# How to verify History page in Selenium Webdriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a Page name Edit Profile ,where I have to verify the history of the page,that is if any one of the field is edited for ex Name  field.History page will show "Name Abc changed to Test ".Like this many fields are there in Edit Profile page.Whatever field I edit,that history should show in History page

How to do this through Selenium Java

Comment: show your code trials, data samples, if you can share url that would be better

Comment: I can't share the url ,as its confidential ,I am new to selenium.Was just checking what logic can be applied to this scenario.

Comment: keep backup of old data or fetch it from source then validate it on page with the values displayed on  page